# Radio button or dropdown to change user input or URL with HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css, url, user-input

So, I'm really rusty with HTML. I wasn't able to google my way through this so far.

I am trying to Use radio buttons or a dropdown menu to change either the whole URL, or just alter a chunk in a URL.
I'm using this to enter in a membership number and create a QR code out of it. I have the QR functionality working just fine, however I would like to be able to change the size determined in the url.
like this :

```html
        <p>Image Size : <select name="size">
            <option value="100x100">100x100</option>
            <option value="150x150">150x150</option>
            <option value="200x200">200x200</option>
            <option value="250x250">250x250</option>
            <option value="300x300" selected="">300x300</option>
            <option value="350x350">350x350</option>
            <option value="400x400">400x400</option>
            <option value="500x500">500x500</option>
        </select></p>
```

But I'm not sure what I need to do to actually make a change.
I imagine we could have it make a whole URL with the + userInput for each option,
or alter the url of the image with various sizes.

This is my working code so far with no size adjustment options.

```html
<html>

<center>
<!--These Comments are not visible on page, Just for backend :) 




<!--This area will grab the member number and create the code -->

<body>
<script>
    function change() {
        var userInput = document.getElementById('userInput').value;
        window.location = "http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=qr&chld=H|0&chs=300x300&chl=" + userInput;
    }
</script>   
<br>
Enter your Membership # to create a Scannable QR Code.
<br>
<!--This section below sets the input type to only allow you to use numbers "1-9", "-", "T" and "G"(capital only) for guest numbers-->

<input type='text' id='userInput' value='' 
    oninput="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9-G-T]/g, '').replace(/(\..*)\./g, '$1');" />
<input type='button' onclick='change()' value='Get QR Code' />
<br>


</center>

<!--Spencer Lewis V0.9.5.4 (7/25/2020)-->
   
<br>

</html>
```

Any help would really be appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you store your QRcode string in a variable and then when the radio button is selected create new variable like
var a=qr
var b=radio value
var c=a+b

and use var c for the qr?

Comment: Honestly, because I had no idea. I'm a total novice when it comes to this stuff. The fruits of my labor so far are from a lot of googling. Thanks for the idea! I'll look into doing variables!  Is [this](https://html-online.com/articles/get-url-parameters-javascript/) what I'm looking for?

Comment: If you are sending variables from one page to another yes. If you are working within one page, and if you don't use complex stuff all variables are available to you instantly